# Merge three heterogenous lists to single list based on an Id using Java 8 and predicates

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, java-8, java-stream

I would like to merge three different types of lists to one list based on a field.

```
A(id, val1)
B(id, val2)
C(id, val3)
D(id, val1, val2, val3)
```

```
List<A> AList;
List<B> BList;
List<C> CList;
```

```
List<D> DList;
```

Merge AList, BList, CList to DList using Stream and Predicates.

One way is merging first AList and BList using n^2 complexity to get DList (with val1 and val2);
then looping DList to fill val3 with CList using n^2 again. So complexity will be
`n^2 + n^2 = n^2`

Q1. Is there a better way to improve complexity?
Q2. I want to use Predicate and Stream to solve this problem, so making readable and short code.

Comment: What do you mean by 'merging'? joining lists without duplicates? are the items sorted?

Comment: If the size of each list is same, meaning the `id`s are consistent in all three lists, you can also sort them by `id` and merge. It would be `O(N*logN)` then. But yeah, as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62949423/1746118), you could also do it in `O(N)`. Just a note about the complexities, it might be worth mentioning the size of each list.

Comment: The size of the list is not much... And also they are not sorted...

Comment: Yes, @GreyFairer... Joining without duplicates and items not sorted

Comment: @Naman This question itself has two parts. One is improving time complexity. I guess [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62949423/1746118) gave a great improvement but the other part is readable shortcode. Also as in the answer provided; extra O(n) space is used, which is again a trade-off (but a good trade-off I agree).  Why I am asking for a predicate solution because it can improve the readability; and surely I will upload the issue I am facing with that solution.

Comment: @pj2494 asking multiple questions in one is not recommended, they can always be linked as separate threads. It would also help to discuss details around complexities in a different thread and implementation-specific doubts in another. On the other hand, `Predicate` might be good to have in the solution you are proposing, but one cannot be sure unless the implementation is shared. So, again, a thread with complexity as this stands right now, completed, then a thread over the implementation details, as you can create another providing the code in use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in `O(n)` if you willing to use `O(n)` extra space.

1. Create three maps (hashmap) out of the three lists - map of `id` to `val1`, map of `id` to `val2`, and map of `id` to `val3` (by iterating the three lists once).
2. Loop through one of the maps and construct `List<D>`. You can access the other `val`s in `O(1)`.

**EDIT:** This assumes the id object has `equals` and `hashcode` implemented.

Comment: I guess you mean a HashMap? Then yes, given a good hashCode for the id objects, that results in O(n).

Comment: @GreyFairer Yes. That is what I meant.